# How to align top of UILabel to top of another UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I want to achieve following UI:

[image]

This UI contains label (which is bold on top), stackview (inside blue rectangle), view (gray line) and two labels below of line.

As you see, I have separate view inside stackview. Here is how its constraints are set:

```
titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(16)
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }

    priceLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-16)
        make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.top)
        make.leading.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.trailing).offset(16)
    }
```

My goal is to align top of the `titleLabel` to top of the `priceLabel`. It seems everything is working, but here is the screenshot of this UI with different text:

[image]

As you see, my stackview doesn't give space for bold label. I don't want it to happen. This UI is shown inside bottom sheet with intrinsic layout. I think the problem is that my priceLabel doesn't have bottom constraint. Let's try to give it:

```
priceLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-16)
        make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.top)
        make.leading.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.trailing).offset(16)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
```

Constraints of `titleLabel` wasn't changed. Here is the result:

[image]

It seems everything is ok, but my first `titleLabel` is too small, even it has `numberOfLines` set to 0. The another problem is that my `priceLabel`'s top is not aligned with `titleLabel`'s top. I don't want it to happen.

After that, I remembered that `UIStackView`  in `UIKit` has `firstBaseline` alignment. Then, I decided to put `titleLabel` and `priceLabel` inside horizontal stackview with `firstBaseline` alignment and `fill` distribution:

```
private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.alignment = .firstBaseline
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 16
    return stackView
}()


 private func setup() {
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(priceLabel)
    addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(16)
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-16)
        make.bottom.top.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

It is totally ruined. The space between my bold label and stackview is too big. Possibly, the reason for that is bold label's  hugging priority.

**Final words**

As you see, problem is in alignment of labels inside stackview. There are dozens of ways of aligning top of uilabels but all of them give different results. I don't know why. It seems that I don't know something from Auto Layout. So, how to achieve the first screenshot's result?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're doing... Is this a subview? Or is it a view controller that you're presenting?

Comment: view controller that is presented using FloatingPanel library

Comment: It's difficult to offer help, without knowing what you're really doing. I grabbed the SCENEE/FloatingPanel repo from GitHub (I assume that's what you're referring to)... if you can show a simple example of what you're trying (see [mre]), it will be much easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is set a height constraint to your bold label. That way it doesn't shrink.

```
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```